# How to pass values dynamically in Script using php to produce graph

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I am trying create a bar chart for the data in mysql using php. I use bootstrap template to create application. I have predefined barchart with static data. I wanna add the data from the database. I tried my best but could not find solution as I am beginner in Javascript. Please guide me to add data dynamically. The Script is below:

```js
 // Bar chart
      var ctx = document.getElementById("mybarChart");
      var mybarChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'bar',
        data: {
          labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
          datasets: [{
            label: '# of Votes',
            backgroundColor: "#26B99A",
            data: [10, 20, 30, 40, 20, 10, 40]
          }, {
            label: '# of Votes',
            backgroundColor: "#03586A",
            data: [41, 56, 25, 48, 72, 34, 12]
          }]
        },

        options: {
          scales: {
            yAxes: [{
              ticks: {
                beginAtZero: true
              }
            }]
          }
        }
      });
```

```html
 <div class="x_content">
                    <canvas id="mybarChart"></canvas>
                  </div>
```

Comment: What does the data look like when coming from DB? General hint: you'll need something like `echo "javascriptdata = " . json_encode($phpdata).";";`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the environment, you have php-produced webpages.
If so I would:

1. Create a .php file
2. Write some php code to connect to the database and to retrieve an array with the data to be charted
3. Copy your JS code, wrapped in `<script> </script>` tags and also wrap it in a JS Function which you'll call later in the page
4. Inside your JS code, after datasets, write a php loop as this:

   ```
   // Bar chart
   var ctx = document.getElementById("mybarChart");
   var mybarChart = new Chart(ctx, {
   type: 'bar',
   data: {
     labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
     datasets: [{
       <?php
       if (count($arrayOfData) > 0){
          echo "label: '# of Votes',";
          echo "backgroundColor: '#26B99A',";
          echo "data: [";
          $firstValue = true;
          foreach ($arrayOfData as $dataValue) {
              if ( ! $firstValue ) {
                 echo ", ".$dataValue;
              } else {
                 $firstValue = false;
              }
              echo $dataValue;
          }
          echo "]";
       } else {
          //Decide what to do if you don't have data
       }
       ?>
     }]
   }'
   ```
5. Write the rest of the HTML/PHP page.

Note that if you want more than 1 bar in your graph you have to also cycle through different data sets, not only through one as I showed above for simplicity.